# Implementation of the Newton-Raphson method to solve a system of nonlinear equations(Speed comparison)

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning

I tried to implement the fastest way of root finding of a system of nonlinear equations but still it is almost two times slower than the embedded FindRoot function in the Mathematica. In the following functions, f is the evaluation of functions and fs is the gradient of the function at the given initial points. The difference of the the following functions lies in the implementation of f and fs. In the first function, **Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction** were used to evaluate Jacobian of the function numerically. In the second function f was compiled and the third one inverse of the Jacobian function was first evaluated symbolically and then used later using **injac** function. I was wondering if someone can help to speed up the functions? possibly with **NestWhile**?

### List of variables used in the functions

- vars= List of variables
- expr= List of equations to be solved
- init= List of initial points
- nit= Number of iterations
- Prints= Printing the norms(norm[x_i+1-x_i] and norm[f[x_i+1]] ) if set to 1
- tol = Tolerence

### Function 1

```
Clear[solve];
solve[vars_List, expr_List, init_List, nit_Integer, Prints_Integer, 
  tol_Real] := 
 Block[{$MinPrecision = 16, $MaxPrecision = 16, ax, res, it = init, 
   f = Function[Evaluate[vars], #] & /@ expr, 
   fs = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[vars, 
     expr, {Length@vars}]},
  Unprotect[In, Out];
  Clear[In, Out];
  Protect[In, Out];
  ClearSystemCache[];
  Table[
   res = N[
     it - Inverse[
         fs["Jacobian"[#]] &@
          N[it, 16]].Transpose[{f[[#]] @@ N[it, 16] & /@ 
           Range[Length@vars]}] // Flatten, 16];
   If[Prints == 1,
    Print["norm[x_i+1-x_i]=", Norm[(it - res), 2]];
    Print["norm[f[x_i+1]]=", 
     Norm[(f[[#]] @@ N[res, 16] & /@ Range[Length@vars]), 2]], 
    Unevaluated[Sequence[]]];
   If[N[Norm[(it - res), 2], 16] < tol, Return["Exit", Table]];
   If[i == nit, Print["Solution has not converged"]];
   it = res, {i, nit}];
  res
  ]
```

### Function 2

```
Clear[solve1];
solve1[vars_List, expr_List, init_List, nit_Integer, Prints_Integer, 
  tol_Real] := 
 Block[{$MinPrecision = 16, $MaxPrecision = 16, ax, res, it = init, 
   f = Compile[##] &[vars, #, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
       "Parallelization" -> True] & /@ expr, 
   fs = Experimental`CreateNumericalFunction[vars, 
     expr, {Length@vars}]},
  Unprotect[In, Out];
  Clear[In, Out];
  Protect[In, Out];
  ClearSystemCache[];
  Table[
   res = N[
     it - Inverse[
         N[fs["Jacobian"[#]], 16] &@
          N[it, 16]].Transpose[{N[f[[#]], 16] @@ N[it, 16] & /@ 
           Range[Length@vars]}] // Flatten, 16];
   If[Prints == 1,
    Print["norm[x_i+1-x_i]=", Norm[(it - res), 2]];
    Print["norm[f[x_i+1]]=", 
     Norm[(f[[#]] @@ N[res, 16] & /@ Range[Length@vars]), 2]], 
    Unevaluated[Sequence[]]];
   If[N[Norm[(it - res), 2], 16] < tol, Return["Exit", Table]];
   If[i == nit, Print["Solution has not converged"]];
   it = res, {i, nit}];
  res
  ]
```

### Function 3

```
injac[f_List?VectorQ, x_List] := 
     Inverse@Outer[D, f, x] /; Equal @@ (Dimensions /@ {f, x});
Clear[solve2];
solve2[vars_List, expr_List, init_List, inv_, nit_Integer, 
  Prints_Integer, tol_Real] := 
 Block[{$MinPrecision = 16, $MaxPrecision = 16, ax, res, it = init, 
   f = Function[Evaluate[vars], #] & /@ expr, fs = inv[expr, vars]},
  Unprotect[In, Out];
  Clear[In, Out];
  Protect[In, Out];
  ClearSystemCache[];
  Table[
   res = N[
     it - (fs /. 
          MapThread[
           Rule, {vars, 
            it}]).Transpose[{N[f[[#]], 16] @@ N[it, 16] & /@ 
           Range[Length@vars]}] // Flatten, 16];
   If[Prints == 1,
    Print["norm[x_i+1-x_i]=", Norm[(it - res), 2]];
    Print["norm[f[x_i+1]]=", 
     Norm[(f[[#]] @@ N[res, 16] & /@ Range[Length@vars]), 2]], 
    Unevaluated[Sequence[]]];
   If[N[Norm[(it - res), 2], 16] < tol, Return["Exit", Table]];
   If[i == nit, Print["Solution has not converged"]];
   it = res, {i, nit}];
  res
  ]
```

### Using the functions and results:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FindRoot` does some fancy checking at each step.  You could avoid that to save time.  I doubt the basic Newton step can be done any faster than it is in `FindRoot` (however it is done).  For an arbitrary n-dimensional solver, you would probably want to use [`LinearSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) than `Inverse`.  Your input shows machine precision numbers, so I don't know if you really wanted to control the precision of the computation with `$MinPrecision` and `$MaxPrecision`.  Those system parameters affect only arbitrary precision numbers but not machine reals or exact numbers. In other words, they have no effect on the examples shown in the OP.

Here's a stripped down solver that's almost twice as fast on a similar 2D example:

```
newtonStep[f_, vars_] := newtonStep[f, D[f, {vars}], vars];
newtonStep[f_, jac_, vars_][x_] := Block[vars,
   vars = x;
   x - LinearSolve[jac, f]];
FixedPoint[
  newtonStep[{x^2 + y^2 - 2, (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5}, {x, y}],
  {1., -2.},
  100,
  SameTest -> Equal] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.00023, {1.4, -0.2}}  *)

FindRoot[{x^2 + y^2 - 2, (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5}, {{x, 1.}, {y, -2.}}] // RepeatedTiming
(*  {0.00040, {x -> 1.4, y -> -0.2}}  *)
```

Note that there is some tolerance in `Equal` when comparing numbers.  On numbers that differ only in their last seven bits, `Equal` will return `True`.

Now, if you want all of the robustness of `FindRoot`, then you have to code up some checks and so forth, and you find the gap in timing starts to close.

Comment: Computing  the symbolic derivative only once in the beginning and creating a function fromt hat should also improve the speed a bit.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It does compute the derivative only once.  Maybe having two forms of `newtonStep` is confusing?

Comment: Ah, now I come to see it. The "double" construction and the `Block`-trick are indeed a bit confusing but very elegant!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher It also depends on `newtonStep` evaluating to the version with the Jacobian before being passed to `FixedPoint`. If `FixedPoint` were `HoldAll`, it might not work efficiently. So one has to think carefully about all those evaluation rules. Every time I have such problem, I think, how neat you can do it this way in *Mathematica*; but every time I have to look at someone else's code, or my old code, I think, now what in the world is going on?!?

Comment: Hm. I think the confusion is mostly caused by the naming of things. I would have found `createNewtonIterator[f_, vars_] := With[{jac = D[f, {vars, 1}]},
   Function[x, Block[vars, vars = x; x - LinearSolve[jac, f]]]
   ];
FixedPoint[
 createNewtonIterator[{x^2 + y^2 - 2, (x - 1)^2 + (y - 2)^2 - 5}, {x, 
   y}], {1., -2.}, 100, SameTest -> Equal]` a bit more transparent. But that's a matter of taste, isn't it? (Although, the pure function created seems to be a tiny bit faster.) Anyway, I learnt something new! Many thanks!

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You're welcome! That's kind of what I had in mind with my first comment. Probably better than `newtonStep = (Function @@ Hold@Block[#3, #3 = #4[1]; #4[1] - LinearSolve[#1, #2]] &[D[#1, {#2}], ##, Slot]) &` :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 very nice and concise!!!